# MATLAB texture mapping: Resize the image using imresize or built-in resize?

Tags: matlab, image-resizing, texture-mapping

I'm plotting a 3D box and I use texture mapping to map the six sides with some images, I use following code line:

```
Z=zeros(height,width);
surface(Z, 'FaceColor','texturemap','EdgeColor','none','Cdata',image);
hold on;
```

And then the next side and so on. What I did so far is that I resized the images using imresize.

```
image = imresize(image,[height width]);
```

My question is if there will be a big difference if I just use the original sized image for texture mapping in terms of resolution and speed? Is it maybe even better not to use imresize? The thing is I'd have to change some code inbetween these lines and also come up with some other solutions but if the resolution of the mapped images would be better without imresize it would be totally worth it.

Comment: What is preventing you from putting a breakpoint before the resize line and checking the resolution of the image?

Comment: How can I see the resolution?I mean of course I know the image size and therefor the number of pixels but I know that the pixels are interpolated when using imresize. What I don't know is if surface() also resizes the image or how this exactly works and if it's maybe better in terms of image resolution?Maybe it wouldn't be hard to tell but I have absolutely no idea how I should do this.

Comment: Perhaps you could just observe a few images and see what has the best quality? I don't know of any theoretical solution to this.